# How to delete a file that is not an image?

Tags: php

I wrote this code to store an image and avoid that someone store a malware or other files different from an image:

```
$content = file_get_contents($image);
file_put_contents($path, $content);

// Check imagesize to know if it is an image or not:
$sizeimage = getimagesize(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path);
if($sizeimage[0]<10000){ echo "ok"; }else{ unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path); }
```

I tried to insert another files like a CSS file and it store the CSS in the database.

Why ? What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2):

In case the image file is invalid, `$sizeimage[0]` returns `0` (check [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)).
Hence, the following statement also validates `true` in case the file is no valid image:

```
if($sizeimage[0]<10000)
```

Consider using the following statement:

```
if($sizeimage[0]>0 && $sizeimage[0]<10000)
```

This only validates `true` when `getimagesize()` found an image that's smaller then 1000 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($sizeimage[0]<10000){ echo "ok"; }else{ unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path); }
```

getimagesize returns false when a file is not an image, but you don't check on that. You use [0], but if that doesn't exist, it becomes "null", which is less than 10000. So:

```
<?php
if($sizeimage !== false && isset($sizeimage[0]) && $sizeimage[0] < 10000 && $imagesize[0] > 0) {
    echo "Okay.";
}
else {
    unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path);
}
```

Comment: Because maybe you still want images whose width are less than 10000?

Comment: Please check the "Return Values" section in the PHP documentation (link in my answer). According to the documentation, index `0` and `1` of `getimagesize()` might return `0` in case the image file is invalid. The `if($sizeimage !== false && isset($sizeimage[0]) && $sizeimage[0] < 10000)` statement might therefore validate `true` even though the file contains no valid image.

Comment: @Anne Fair enough, but getimagesize may return false in case of an invalid image. The ultimate solution is a combination of our answers.

Comment: Updated the example, now accounts for all possible return values for an invalid image.

Comment: In case `getimagesize()` returns `false`, the `if($sizeimage[0]>0 && $sizeimage[0]<10000)` statement still returns `false`. Hence, there is no need to add additional conditions. That's the beauty of PHP, it works perfect with unset/uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Anne indeed, but it would emit an E_NOTICE, because you're accessing `$sizeimage[0]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Your statement `if($sizeimage !== false && isset($sizeimage[0]) && $sizeimage[0] < 10000 && $imagesize[0] > 0)` would **also** emit an `E_NOTICE` because it always compares `$imagesize[0]` to `10000` and `0`, also when the first two conditions are `false`. All conditions in the statement will be checked during execution. To prevent the `E_NOTICE`, you need to nest `if($sizeimage[0] < 10000 && $imagesize[0] > 0)` into `if(isset($sizeimage[0]))` and nest that into `if($sizeimage !== false)`. Which is quite ugly :)

Comment: @Anne Are you saying that `true && false && true` evaluates all three conditions? Because it doesn't. It stops at the very first false. if isset returns false, there is no check on `$imagesize[0]`. Try this yourself if you don't believe me; PHP's check is from left to right.

Comment: Code: `if(a() && b() && c()) echo "true"; function a(){return true;} function b(){return false;} function c(){echo "C"; return true;}`  Wow, the last condition is indeed never checked, that's new to me. Other languages I'm working more extensively with do check all conditions within the `if` statement (just checked), I wrongfully assumed this also applied to PHP. Thank you for making me aware :)

Answer (score 1):

getimagesize will return `false` on error. This means that:

- `$sizeimage = false`
- `$sizeimage[0] = null`
- `null` converts to `0` and `0 < 10000`

Answer (score 1):

Please check file extension. If its not valid extension then don't allow.

[see PHP example here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))) { echo 'valid file'; }else { echo 'invalid file type';}
```

To delete a file, use PHP [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 0):

I revised your code as follows:

```
$content = file_get_contents($image);
file_put_contents($path,$content);

// Check imagesize to know if it is an image or not:

$sizeimage = getimagesize(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path);
if($sizeimage){ echo "ok"; } else { unlink(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$path); }
```

This should work. The unlink will be executed when $sizeimage is null or false.

There is a better way to really tell if the file is an image by checking it's mime-type. See **finfo_file** (PHP 4) or **finfo** (PHP 5).